# How to detect tap on Flutter Flame v1.0.0-rc6 and later?

Tags: flutter, flame

What's the equivalent of:

```
TapGestureRecognizer tapper = TapGestureRecognizer(); 
tapper.onTapDown = game.onTapDown; 
flameUtil.addGestureRecognizer(tapper);
```

in Flame 1.0.0-rc6 and later ?

I've tried many ways to detect tap but it don't seems to work. It was working before the  `AddGestureRecognizer` removing update.

Thank you :)

Comment: https://flame-engine.org/docs/#/input This might help.

Comment: I've already read this but somehow, it won't work on my code ... But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error,

my UI (menu, life etc...) was "over" the touch detection so onTapDown wasn't able to detect any touch because it was under.

I solved it by reducing my containers's sizes to be able to reach the "bottom" layer of onTapDown.

Answer (score 0):

I also looked for an alternative as I had the issue that "addGestureRecognizer" is deprecated now.

I solved it with implementing the TapDetector to the Game like this.

```
class GameController extends Game implements TapDetector {...}
```

The Flame Doc https://flame-engine.org/docs/#/input used the "with"-Keyword. But it didn't worked for me.